# Git pull keeps saying "already-up-to-date"

Tags: git, github

I'm having problem with pulling my repository.
one of my members pushed his version, when I try to pull it keeps on saying "already-up-to-date". My member says he cloned the current version, also he is new, me and my previous member are the only ones who made this repository. then he left, and has been replaced by a new member, so he signed in to a new account, and he is already on my repository, now he tried to push and it's okay, now I can't push. Also me and my previous member doesn't have any problem in doing this. This is the 1st time, that me and my new member tried pushing and pulling.

Comment: Are the other guy's commits showing up in github when you look on the website directly? And what error do you get when you try to push?

Comment: Maybe the branch *is* up-to-date and another branch just needs to be switched to (and have work done on it)?

Comment: yes it shows @Endareth

Comment: we are just working on one branch in "master"

Answer (score -1):

If he is pushing and it is posting to github but you are unable to pull. You potentially made changes to the file. I would say attempt to rebase the file tree. This should get things bank into order.